# Ruby global variables in Strings being evaluated/truncated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, escaping

I have some credentials that I need read into Ruby, but the problem is that they have `#$` repeated several times in them. The behavior of said character sequence is as follows:

```
> "123#$123"
=> "123"
```

For some reason, Ruby evaluates the `$1` (which is `nil` because no regex happened before). Is there any way to avoid this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: It'd probably help if you explain what you're trying to do that results in those strings. Currently it looks like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)" where you're trying to clean up the string after doing something in the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah I think I asked this question prematurely. Didn't lay out all the different variables. Turns out the actual problem was in an unrelated plugin that was doing some very weird `sed` substitution. Needless to say, Ruby is not the problem. We can close this question or whatever.

Comment: You can delete the question if it's not of value to the community. As asked it won't help anyone in the future because there's not enough information to tie it to a particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote instead of double quote:

```
irb(main):005:0> '123#$123'    
=> "123\#$123"
```

Or otherwise, escape the `$` char:

```
irb(main):006:0> "123#\$123"
=> "123\#$123"
```

Comment: I guess I should have clarified...ultimately I want to load this variable via Rails' `secrets.yml` file (which would read it in via `ENV['THE_STRING_I_WANT']`), and then access it via `Rails.application.secrets.the_string_i_want`, so I don't think I have that kind of control (to use single quotes that is).

Comment: YAML doesn't interpolate like this, so you should be fine.

Comment: @user701847: YAML is a completely different language. It has nothing whatsoever to do with Ruby. Its syntax is completely different, its semantics are completely different. Ruby string interpolation simply doesn't exist in YAML, because Ruby string interpolation is a feature of Ruby and YAML has nothing to do with Ruby.